# How to show folder tree in Google Picker

Tags: google-picker

I want to show in `google.picker.DocsView` both my and shared with me files and folders, with the folder structure.

If I do not add `setIncludeFolders(true)`, all files are listed, but folders are missing.

If I add `setIncludeFolders(true)`, files and folders of all levels are listed.

I can add `.setOwnedByMe(true)` or `.setOwnedByMe(false)`. This fixes the folders structure issue. But in this case I cannot show both my and shared with me files in one view.

Or I can add `.setParent('root')`. But then shared files and folders are missing.

Is it possible to show all files and folders, but respecting the folder structure?

Comment: As per writing, it is not possible to show to show a tree like browsing mode as what was discussed in the support forum of [Picker API forum](https://developers.google.com/picker/forum). `List and Grid mode are the only modes supported for Drive views`. If you search for the topic, "How can I get a hierarchical view of folders?" it will show the forum where this was discussed by a Google Docs Engineer.

Comment: MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, thank you! I have found the thread. Actually, I do not need a separate view. Functions `setOwnedByMe` and `setParent` do what I want. But they limit the list to only my or only shared with me files and folders. But I want to show both. IMHO, it is very strange architectural decision, that these functions control whether the hierarchy of folders is respected or ignored.

Comment: @Alex, indeed Google is strange in many ways. Now it is easy to do complex things and hard or impossible to do simple things. Welcome to the 21-st Century!